# Using line.rfind to find a changing variable

Tags: python, datetime

I am using line.rfind to find the day of week. The script I have runs every day, and I always need to find the next day in some html script. For instance, if today is Friday, I need to use line.rfind to find "Saturday" within the html code. I tried the script below...but for obvious reasons it did not work since it is trying to find everything within the single quotes.

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import urllib
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date = datetime.now()
date1 = date + timedelta(days=1)

class city :
        def __init__(self, city_name, link, latitude, longitude) :
                self.name = city_name
                self.url = link
                self.low0 = 0
                self.high1 = 0
                self.high2 = 0
                self.low1 = 0
                self.low2 = 0
                self.lat = latitude
                self.long = longitude

        def retrieveTemps(self) :
                filehandle = urllib.urlopen(self.url)

                # get lines from result into array
                lines = filehandle.readlines()

                # (for each) loop through each line in lines
                line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
                for line in lines:
                        line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter

                        # find string, position otherwise position is -1

                        position0 = line.rfind('title="%(x)" % {"x": date1.strftime("%A")}')
```

The exact line in the html code that I am trying to pull the day from is...

```
<abbr title="Saturday">Sat</abbr>
```

I need to find 'title="Saturday"' as opposed to just "Saturday" because the day of the week is sometimes mentioned before this line. Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks!

EDIT -- Adding in next few lines of code.

```
# string is found in line
if position0 > 0 :
        self.low0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is that your string substitution is not the right python syntax.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date1 = datetime.now()
>>> 'title="%(x)" % {"x": date1.strftime("%A")}'
'title="%(x)" % {"x": date1.strftime("%A")}'
>>> 'title="{}"'.format(date1.strftime("%A"))
'title="Friday"'
```

Unrelated, but another thing I noticed is this:

```
line_number = 0 # a counter for line number
for line in lines:
  line_number = line_number + 1 # increment counter
```

You should prefer: `for line_number, line in enumerate(lines):`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you. And thanks for the tip, I will try that out. However, I have come across another problem that I never had before once I made the changes regarding the line.rfind. 

The next line of code I have (not shown above) is this...

 if position0 > 0 :
    self.low0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('&')[0].split('>')[-1]

and when I run my script I get the error that says the ":" is an invalid syntax. Not sure why making those changes would give me that error...

Comment: You may need to post a new question so as not to make this one into a [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/162650)

Comment: I have edited the initial question to include the next few lines of code.